# How can I show that $(a^\top \otimes b)(b^\top \otimes a) = (a \otimes b)(b \otimes a)^\top$?

Tags: tensor-products, vectors

Let symbol $\otimes$ denotes the Kronecker product, $a \in \mathbb R^n$ and $b \in \mathbb R^m$.

How can I show that $(a^\top \otimes bb^\top \otimes a) = (ba^\top \otimes ab^\top)$ ?

My final goal is to show that the commutation matrix $K^{m,n}$ can be computed in various ways, including:
\begin{gather}
\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^m e_{n,i} e_{m,j}^\top \otimes e_{m,j} e_{n,i}^\top \\
\sum_{i=1}^n e_{n,i} \otimes I_m \otimes e_{n,i}^\top \\
\sum_{j=1}^m e_{m,j}^\top \otimes I_n \otimes e_{m,j}
\end{gather}
The question I am asking is the only step where I'm a little stuck. And I have the feeling it's really easy.

Comment: Maybe most of this is showing that $(b\otimes a)^\top=b^\top\otimes a^\top$.  That would get you $(a^\top\otimes b)(b^\top\otimes a)$ equal to the expression you have on the right.  Next I'm wondering about equality between that and $a^\top\otimes (bb^\top)\otimes a$. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have it. As Expected it's really incredibly easy.

For vectors $a \in \mathbb R^n$ and $b \in \mathbb R^m$, $a^\top \otimes b = ba^\top = b^\top \otimes a$.

It easy to see:
\begin{align}
(a^\top \otimes b) = \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^m a_ib_j e_{m,j} e_{n,i}^\top = \left(\sum_{j=1}^m b_j e_{m,j}\right)\left(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i e_{n,i}^\top\right) = ba^\top
\end{align}

From there, $ba^\top \otimes ab^\top = a^\top \otimes b \otimes b^\top \otimes a = a^\top \otimes bb^\top \otimes a$.

Comment: You proved what you asked in the *body* of your question, but the *title* of your question is unproven (because it's false).